# Throwing and logging Exceptions, a better way

Tags: java, error-handling

Ultimately, i'd like to

```
if (badThingsHappen) {
 log the issue
 throw exception with description
}
```

The obvious redundancy here is that often exception description and the message to be logged is (often) the same.

This looks needlessly verbose

```
if (badThingsHappen) {
 logger.error("oh no! not again!");
 throw new AppException("oh no! not again!");
}
```

Declaring temporary String feels wrong

```
if (badThingsHappen) {
 String m = "oh no! not again!";
 logger.error(m);
 throw new AppException(m);
}
```

**Is it ok to have Exception's constructor handle the logging? Is there a better (cleaner) way?**

Comment: I think you need not log statement before exception, you would define the message either in your custom exception or in generic ones

Comment: Assuming your exception is caught by the calling class (hopefully it is the case), most of the time, you don't want to log AND rethrow, because the calling class will probably log too.

Comment: have you considered AOP? http://www.voelter.de/data/articles/aop/aop.html

Comment: @assylias I see your point .. for the purposes of this program, i'd like to log it as soon as issue happens. But i see your point

Comment: I agree with assylias, logging the exception counts as 'handling' the exception. It should be done by the catch statement which handles it gracefully.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072343/throw-exception-vs-logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a utility method:

```
public class AppException extends Exception {
    public static AppException logAndThrow(Logger logger, String message) throws AppException {
        AppException e = new AppException(message);
        // log the stack trace as well
        logger.error(message, e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and the use it:

```
if (badThingsHappen) {
    AppException.logAndThrow(logger, "oh no! not again!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer to log exceptions when I catch them, rather then when I throw them.

This cleans up the logs quite a bit more, and also lets the "client" code handle the exception and information output much more precisely, since the information you want to associate with the exception when logging can be dependent of context.

If you *do* want to log as soon as it happens, I would build the exception and log it before throwing, something like:

```
if(badthingshappen){
    Exception e = new Exception("holy $%##");
    logger.log(e);
    throw e;
}
```

A bit verbose yes... but this *is* java.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when working with Exceptions and logging requirements I include logging support in the Exceptions.

Exceptions *typically* inherit from a Base Exception class in our project and it has hooks for logging `log4j` or other logging utilities.

```
class Problem extends java.lang.Exception {
  private boolean debug=false;
  public Problem(String message) {
    if(debug) {
      logging.exception(message);
      /* Maybe a stack trace? */
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the application, we used it in our first iteration but later dumped it because we started relying on exceptions to report small problems (poor design) but our CORE Exceptions still log, the other exceptions don't log because when it's a large application you take performance hits.

Comment: The thing I like about this pattern is that you have the option (debug) to decide if the exceptions get logged.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an error-logging method myself, today (this is used to log errors if they occur in a listener method, so it's also logging the method in which the error occurred and the object in which the listener is implemented to help tracking):

```
protected void listenerError(String listenerMethodName, Object listener,
        RuntimeException e) {
    logger.error("Exception while calling " + listenerMethodName
            + " on object " + listener, e);
    throw e;

}
```

I wrote it in the class in question (or the base class, to be exact), because you probably want to use the logger in that class (and all subclasses). Another option would be to create a utility method in a utility class (I would not write an Exception class for it), and provide the logger as parameter:

```
class ExceptionUtil {

  public static error(Exception e, Logger logger) {
     logger.error(e);
     throw e;
  }
}
```

You can, of course, provide the method and object as params for this method (or an overloaded version of it), as necessary.